# Publish maven project to a local directory

Tags: java, maven

I want to publish my maven project to a local directory but **not** in `$HOME/.m2/repository`. I have created the following directory structure:

```
$HOME/myrepo
|- third_party
+- private
```

The directory `$HOME/myrepo/third_party` holds, as the name suggests, external artifacts from 3rd parties. I want to publish my own projects into `$HOME/myrepo/private`. Therefore, I use the following adjusted `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>maven-private</id>
      <username></username>
      <password></password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>maven-local</id>
      <url>file:///home/user/myrepo/third_party</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

The file `pom.xml` for my test project looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>maven-private</id>
      <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
      <url>file:///home/user/myrepo/private</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

When I run

```
mvn install
```

The project compiles successfully and all required files are fetched from `$HOME/myrepo/third_party`, however, after compilation the project is always installed to `$HOME/.m2/repository`.

How do I have to configure maven in order to publish my projects into the `$HOME/myrepo/private` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put the artifacts in a repository other than local, you are not thinking of *installing* but *deploying* them. Installing with maven by definition puts the artifacts in local repository - so unless you intend to overwrite the location of `.m2/repository` and **all** its contents, just run

```
mvn deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of your local Maven repository, i.e. where artifacts are installed, by editing the Maven settings file `~/.m2/settings.xml`. Specifically, you are interested in changing the `<localRepository>` to directory of your choice. One thing to look out for is that path you specify must be an absolute path according to the [Configuring your Local Repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html#configuring-your-local-repository) section of the user guide. Please also note that this will affect *all* artifacts (both your private and 3rd party ones) as Maven only supports a single local repository.

Example:

```xml
<settings>
  <!-- settings -->

  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo/</localRepository>

  <!-- more settings -->
</settings>
```